# Yii2 how can I use a like query for first character only

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

How can I use a like query and limit to the first character only for example my code below works however it does it for all characters for example if an item was called end it would appear in e, n & d rather than just e the starting character/letter.

Current Query/Code

```
    public function actionAlphabet($id)
{
    $this->layout = 'directory';

    $query = Directory::find()
    ->where(['LIKE', 'name', $id]);

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query
    ]);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should simply try :

```
$query = Directory::find()
    ->where(['LIKE', 'name', $id.'%', false]);
```

> Sometimes, you may want to add the percentage characters to the matching value by yourself, you may supply a third operand false to do so. For example, `['like', 'name', '%tester', false]` will generate name `LIKE '%tester'`.

Read more : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-queryinterface.html#where()-detail

EDIT: my mistake, updated thanks to *Latikov Dmitry* comment.

Comment: I tried your suggestion however get no results for E even though the name begins with E (END)

Comment: it's a letter so will be anything from A - Z i guess calling it id isn't ideal but without it kind of works as any name that has an E, N or D will bring results but I only want to query the first letter of the name field

Comment: Check sql log to take a look at the corresponding query

Comment: where(['LIKE', 'name', $id.'%', false]);